# Angular 4 HTTP GET not including JWT for Authorization in HTTP Header

Tags: node.js, angular, http, authorization, jwt

**Challenge**

An Angular module sends JWT tokens to the server with a GET request in order to authenticate that the user is logged in, with the purpose of retrieving their data.

**Source of problem(?)**

The module in question looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {tokenNotExpired} from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

authToken: any;

    getProfile() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.loadToken();
        headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.get(LOCAL_URI + 'admin/profile', headers)
          .map(res => res.json());
      }

  }
```

**Desired result**

The desired result, would be for the token to make it to the server, as I can replicate on Postman, which sends a header with "Authorization": "JWT token..." and returns a proper response with a JSON object including the user profile data.

This used to work perfectly using Angular 2.4 libraries but upon upgrading to Angular 4.2.4, it no longer works and yields the following response from the server:

> Response with status: 401 Unauthorized for URL:
>   http://localhost:3000/admin/profile

**Observations**

If I make Angular use JSON.stringify() on the header in the web console, it looks like this:

```
{
  "Authorization":["JWT long_hash_number..."],
  "Content-Type":["application/json"]
}
```

If I take **req** in the server side (using a NodeJS app employing Passport JWT), the request object contains this _passport field:

{
    "instance": {
        "_key":"passport",
        "_strategies":{
            "session":{
                "name":"session"
            },
            "jwt":{
                "name":"jwt",
                "_secretOrKey":"Ihopethisstayssecret",
                "_verifOpts":{}
                }
            },
            "_serializers":[],
            "_deserializers":[],
            "_infoTransformers":[],
            "_framework":{},
            "_userProperty":"user",
            "strategies":{}
        }
}

**package.json*

```
{
  ....,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angular2-flash-messages": "^2.0.4",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot just pass `headers` as a parameter like you are. You need to wrap it in an object. Like below:

```
getProfile() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get(LOCAL_URI + 'admin/profile', { headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
}
```

That parameter is of type [`RequestOptions`](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions), which can include more than just headers.

If you ever get around to moving to Angular 4.3 or higher, consider using the new [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http) rather that `Http`. `Http` is deprecated, and will go away in a future release.

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked that detail. That does exactly as you say. Will keep in mind that this is being deprecated.